# Изменить тип текста по select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужна ваша помощь. У меня есть кнопка, по клику она добавляет текст из выбранный настроек.По клику на текст, я могу поменять тип текста. Например, в начале я выбрал h1, а в настройках, я могу поменять этот текст на h5, но при выборе, у меня добавляется еще один текст и без этих настроек. Помогите пожалуйста.

```js
function addText() {
    var type = $(".select-txt").val();
    var align = $(".form-align").val();
    var typeEdit = $('.select-txt-type').val();
    var float = "text-align:";
    var id = Date.now();
    var editBlock = "$('.edit-block')";
    var display = ",'block'";
    var colorValue = $(".color").val();
    var color = "color:";
    var closeTag = ";";
    var onclick = 'onclick="editTextColour(this)"';
    var ordinary = "<div class='text-" + align + "' id=" + id + " " + onclick + " contenteditable style=" + float + align + closeTag +
        ">text</div>";
    var h = "<" + type + " class='text-" + align + "' id=" + id + " " + onclick + " contenteditable style=" + float + align + ">text</" + type + ">";

    if (type == "ordinary") {
        $(".preview").append(ordinary);

    } else if (type.startsWith("h")) {
        $(".preview").append(h);
    }


    $(".color").minicolors({
        defaultValue: "#000"
    });
    $(".color").on("change", function() {
        var colorValue = $(".color").val();
        $('.preview .editing').css('color', colorValue);
    });

}
var typeEdit = $('.select-txt-type').val();
var hEditor = "<" +typeEdit+ ">text</" +typeEdit+ ">";
var spanEditor = "<span>text</span>";
$('.select-txt-type').on('change',function(){
    $('.preview').removeClass('editing');
    if (typeEdit == "span") {
        $(".preview .editing").append(spanEditor);
        $(".preview").addClass('editing');
    }
    else if (typeEdit.startsWith("h")) {
        $(".preview .editing").append(hEditor);
        $(".preview").addClass('editing');
    }
  });
function showTextWindow() {
    var modal = $(".modal-txt-container");
    if (modal.css('display', "none")) {
        modal.css('display', "grid");
    } else {
        modal.css('display', "none");
    }
}

function showTextWindow() {
    var modal = document.querySelector(".modal-txt-container");
    if (modal.currentStyle) {
        var displayStyle = modal.currentStyle.display;
    } else if (window.getComputedStyle) {
        var displayStyle = window.getComputedStyle(modal, null).getPropertyValue("display");
    }

    if (displayStyle == "none") {
        modal.style.display = "grid";
    } else {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}

function showElement() {
    var modal = document.querySelector(".choose-option");
    var add = document.querySelector('.add');
    if (modal.currentStyle) {
        var displayStyle = modal.currentStyle.display;
    } else if (window.getComputedStyle) {
        var displayStyle = window.getComputedStyle(modal, null).getPropertyValue("display");
    }

    if (displayStyle == "none") {
        modal.style.display = "grid";
    } else {
        modal.style.display = "none";
        add.style.display = "block";
    }
}


function editTextColour(elem) {
 $('.editing').removeClass('editing');
 $(elem).addClass('editing');
 $('.edit-block').show();
}
```

```css
* {
    outline: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .choose-option {
      background-color: #352a2c;
      position: fixed;
      color: white;
      font-family: 'Scada', sans-serif;
      padding: 15px;
      width: 14%;
  }
  .insert-txt-block {
      padding-bottom: 3%;
      font-size: 1.3em;
  }
  .btn-txt::before {
    content: '\f031';
    font-family: "fontAwesome";
    margin-right: 3%;
}
.btn-txt {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    list-style: none;
    transition: 0.1s;
    padding: 5px;
}
.btn-txt:hover {
  background-color: #727272;
}
.modal-insert-txt {
    background-color: #352a2c;
    color: white;  
    font-family: 'Scada', sans-serif;  
    padding: 20px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    width: 130%;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.modal-txt-container {
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;   
    right: 0;   
    left: 0;  
    position: fixed;
    top: 15%;
    display: none;
}
.container {
  position: fixed;
}
select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: 0 !important;
    background-image: none;
    width: 85%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 .5em;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: black;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 1px 0px 0px 1px;
}
.form-group::after {
    content: '\25BC';
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0 0.5em;
    background: rgb(59, 61, 52);
    pointer-events: none;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    -webkit-transition: .25s all ease;
    -o-transition: .25s all ease;
    transition: .25s all ease;
    color: white;
}
.form-group {
    position: relative;
display: block;
height: 1.7em;
margin: 1% 0% 5% 0;
border: 1px solid #272822;
}
.btn-insert-txt {
    border: none;
    color: white;
    background: #ff5959;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.01em; 
    border-radius: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.btn-insert-txt:hover {
    background: #e54040;
}
.modal-insert-txt span {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
.modal-insert-txt h2 {
    padding-bottom: 2%;
}
.modal-insert-txt hr {
    margin-bottom: 3%;
}
.flex-close-title {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.type-insert li {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.close {
    font-size: 1.7em;
    margin-top: -1%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.close::after {
    content: '\f057';
    font-family: "fontAwesome";
    color: #ff5959;
}
.add {
    font-size: 2em;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    left: 1%;
    top: 2%;
}
.add::after {
    content: '\f055';
    font-family: "fontAwesome";
    color: #ff5959;
}
#textarea-edit {
    width: 80%;
height: 100px;
resize: none;
border: 2px solid #3B3D45;
background: #3B3D45;
color: white;
padding: 4%;
font-size: 1.05em;
border-radius: 4px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
position: relative;
top: 1%;
}
.edit-block {
    background: #272822;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100vh;
    float: right;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Scada', sans-serif;  
    padding: 20px;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
}
.edit-block span {
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
.minicolors-theme-default .minicolors-input {
    height: 29px !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Site Bilder</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Scada:400,700&amp;subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.minicolors/2.1.2/jquery.minicolors.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.minicolors/2.1.2/jquery.minicolors.css">
</head>
<body>

  <span class="add" onclick="showElement()"></span>

<div class="choose-option">
     
<div class="flex-close-title">
<div class="insert-txt-block">Добавить элементы</div>
     <span class="close" onclick="showElement()"></span>
</div>
      <ul class="type-insert">
      <li class="btn-txt" onclick="showTextWindow()">Текст</li>
      </ul>

      </div>

      <div class="modal-txt-container">
<div class="modal-insert-txt">
<h2>Вставить текст</h2>
<hr>
          <span>Тип Текста</span>
           <div class="form-group">
          <select class="select-txt">
            <option value="ordinary" selected>Обычный текст</option>
            <option value="h1">h1</option>
            <option value="h2">h2</option>
            <option value="h3">h3</option>
            <option value="h4">h4</option>
            <option value="h5">h5</option>
            <option value="h6">h6</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        
          <span>Выравнивание текста</span>
          <div class="form-group">  
          <select class="form-align">
            <option value="left">Слева</option>
            <option value="center">По центру</option>
            <option value="right">Справа</option>
          </select>
        </div>

         <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn-insert-txt" onclick="addText()">Вставить текст</button>
      </div>
      </div>
        </div>


    <div class="preview">


</div>

<div class="edit-block">
<div class="wrap">
      <span class="title">
Тип текста
</span><br>
<div class="form-group-txt">
          <select class="select-txt-type">
            <option value="span" selected>Обычный текст</option>
            <option value="h1">h1</option>
            <option value="h2">h2</option>
            <option value="h3">h3</option>
            <option value="h4">h4</option>
            <option value="h5">h5</option>
            <option value="h6">h6</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <span class="title">Выравнивание текста</span>
          <div class="form-group">  
          <select class="form-align">
            <option value="left">Слева</option>
            <option value="center">По центру</option>
            <option value="right">Справа</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <span class="title">
Стили текста
</span><br>
<div class="form-group">
          <select class="select-txt">
            <option value="ordinary" selected>Обычный текст</option>
            <option value="bolder">Жирный шрифт</option>
            <option value="oblique">Наклонный шрифт</option>
            <option value="italic ">Курсив</option>
            <option value="lighter">Светлое начертание</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <span class="title">
Шрифт
</span><br>
<div class="form-group">
          <select class="select-txt">
            <option value="ordinary" selected>Обычный текст</option>
            <option value="bolder">Жирный шрифт</option>
            <option value="oblique">Наклонный шрифт</option>
            <option value="italic ">Курсив</option>
            <option value="lighter">Светлое начертание</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <span class="title">
Цвет
</span><br>
        <input type="text" id="hue" class="color" data-control="hue">
      </div>
</div>

  <script src="js/app.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Вы получаете тип typeEdit при загрузке старницы, а при выполнении события change не вычитываете новое значение. И оно у вас всегда то которое было при загрузке т.е span. Вам надо поместить переопределение нового значения в функцию.

2) Вы используете метод append - он добавляет к выбранному элементу еще одни, а не заменяет на новый.

```js
function addText() {
    var type = $(".select-txt").val();
    var align = $(".form-align").val();
    var typeEdit = $('.select-txt-type').val();
    var float = "text-align:";
    var id = Date.now();
    var editBlock = "$('.edit-block')";
    var display = ",'block'";
    var colorValue = $(".color").val();
    var color = "color:";
    var closeTag = ";";
    var onclick = 'onclick="editTextColour(this)"';
    var ordinary = "<div class='text-" + align + "' id=" + id + " " + onclick + " contenteditable style=" + float + align + closeTag +
        ">text</div>";
    var h = "<" + type + " class='text-" + align + "' id=" + id + " " + onclick + " contenteditable style=" + float + align + ">text</" + type + ">";

    if (type == "ordinary") {
        $(".preview").append(ordinary);

    } else if (type.startsWith("h")) {
        $(".preview").append(h);
    }


    $(".color").minicolors({
        defaultValue: "#000"
    });
    $(".color").on("change", function() {
        var colorValue = $(".color").val();
        $('.preview .editing').css('color', colorValue);
    });

}

$('.select-txt-type').on('change',function(){
var typeEdit = $('.select-txt-type').val();
var hEditor = "<" +typeEdit+ ">text</" +typeEdit+ ">";
var spanEditor = "<span>text</span>";
    $('.preview').removeClass('editing');
    if (typeEdit == "span") {
        $(".preview .editing").html(spanEditor);
        $(".preview").addClass('editing');
    }
    else if (typeEdit.startsWith("h")) {
        $(".preview .editing").html(hEditor);
        $(".preview").addClass('editing');
    }
  });
function showTextWindow() {
    var modal = $(".modal-txt-container");
    if (modal.css('display', "none")) {
        modal.css('display', "grid");
    } else {
        modal.css('display', "none");
    }
}

function showTextWindow() {
    var modal = document.querySelector(".modal-txt-container");
    if (modal.currentStyle) {
        var displayStyle = modal.currentStyle.display;
    } else if (window.getComputedStyle) {
        var displayStyle = window.getComputedStyle(modal, null).getPropertyValue("display");
    }

    if (displayStyle == "none") {
        modal.style.display = "grid";
    } else {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}

function showElement() {
    var modal = document.querySelector(".choose-option");
    var add = document.querySelector('.add');
    if (modal.currentStyle) {
        var displayStyle = modal.currentStyle.display;
    } else if (window.getComputedStyle) {
        var displayStyle = window.getComputedStyle(modal, null).getPropertyValue("display");
    }

    if (displayStyle == "none") {
        modal.style.display = "grid";
    } else {
        modal.style.display = "none";
        add.style.display = "block";
    }
}


function editTextColour(elem) {
 $('.editing').removeClass('editing');
 $(elem).addClass('editing');
 $('.edit-block').show();
}
```

```css
* {
    outline: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  .choose-option {
      background-color: #352a2c;
      position: fixed;
      color: white;
      font-family: 'Scada', sans-serif;
      padding: 15px;
      width: 14%;
  }
  .insert-txt-block {
      padding-bottom: 3%;
      font-size: 1.3em;
  }
  .btn-txt::before {
    content: '\f031';
    font-family: "fontAwesome";
    margin-right: 3%;
}
.btn-txt {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    list-style: none;
    transition: 0.1s;
    padding: 5px;
}
.btn-txt:hover {
  background-color: #727272;
}
.modal-insert-txt {
    background-color: #352a2c;
    color: white;  
    font-family: 'Scada', sans-serif;  
    padding: 20px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    width: 130%;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.modal-txt-container {
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;   
    right: 0;   
    left: 0;  
    position: fixed;
    top: 15%;
    display: none;
}
.container {
  position: fixed;
}
select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: 0 !important;
    background-image: none;
    width: 85%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 .5em;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: black;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 1px 0px 0px 1px;
}
.form-group::after {
    content: '\25BC';
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0 0.5em;
    background: rgb(59, 61, 52);
    pointer-events: none;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    -webkit-transition: .25s all ease;
    -o-transition: .25s all ease;
    transition: .25s all ease;
    color: white;
}
.form-group {
    position: relative;
display: block;
height: 1.7em;
margin: 1% 0% 5% 0;
border: 1px solid #272822;
}
.btn-insert-txt {
    border: none;
    color: white;
    background: #ff5959;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.01em; 
    border-radius: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.btn-insert-txt:hover {
    background: #e54040;
}
.modal-insert-txt span {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
.modal-insert-txt h2 {
    padding-bottom: 2%;
}
.modal-insert-txt hr {
    margin-bottom: 3%;
}
.flex-close-title {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.type-insert li {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.close {
    font-size: 1.7em;
    margin-top: -1%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.close::after {
    content: '\f057';
    font-family: "fontAwesome";
    color: #ff5959;
}
.add {
    font-size: 2em;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    left: 1%;
    top: 2%;
}
.add::after {
    content: '\f055';
    font-family: "fontAwesome";
    color: #ff5959;
}
#textarea-edit {
    width: 80%;
height: 100px;
resize: none;
border: 2px solid #3B3D45;
background: #3B3D45;
color: white;
padding: 4%;
font-size: 1.05em;
border-radius: 4px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
position: relative;
top: 1%;
}
.edit-block {
    background: #272822;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100vh;
    float: right;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Scada', sans-serif;  
    padding: 20px;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
}
.edit-block span {
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
.minicolors-theme-default .minicolors-input {
    height: 29px !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Site Bilder</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Scada:400,700&amp;subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.minicolors/2.1.2/jquery.minicolors.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.minicolors/2.1.2/jquery.minicolors.css">
</head>
<body>

  <span class="add" onclick="showElement()"></span>

<div class="choose-option">
     
<div class="flex-close-title">
<div class="insert-txt-block">Добавить элементы</div>
     <span class="close" onclick="showElement()"></span>
</div>
      <ul class="type-insert">
      <li class="btn-txt" onclick="showTextWindow()">Текст</li>
      </ul>

      </div>

      <div class="modal-txt-container">
<div class="modal-insert-txt">
<h2>Вставить текст</h2>
<hr>
          <span>Тип Текста</span>
           <div class="form-group">
          <select class="select-txt">
            <option value="ordinary" selected>Обычный текст</option>
            <option value="h1">h1</option>
            <option value="h2">h2</option>
            <option value="h3">h3</option>
            <option value="h4">h4</option>
            <option value="h5">h5</option>
            <option value="h6">h6</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        
          <span>Выравнивание текста</span>
          <div class="form-group">  
          <select class="form-align">
            <option value="left">Слева</option>
            <option value="center">По центру</option>
            <option value="right">Справа</option>
          </select>
        </div>

         <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn-insert-txt" onclick="addText()">Вставить текст</button>
      </div>
      </div>
        </div>


    <div class="preview">


</div>

<div class="edit-block">
<div class="wrap">
      <span class="title">
Тип текста
</span><br>
<div  class="form-group-txt">
          <select id="typeEdit" class="select-txt-type">
            <option value="span" selected>Обычный текст</option>
            <option value="h1">h1</option>
            <option value="h2">h2</option>
            <option value="h3">h3</option>
            <option value="h4">h4</option>
            <option value="h5">h5</option>
            <option value="h6">h6</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <span class="title">Выравнивание текста</span>
          <div class="form-group">  
          <select class="form-align">
            <option value="left">Слева</option>
            <option value="center">По центру</option>
            <option value="right">Справа</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <span class="title">
Стили текста
</span><br>
<div class="form-group">
          <select class="select-txt">
            <option value="ordinary" selected>Обычный текст</option>
            <option value="bolder">Жирный шрифт</option>
            <option value="oblique">Наклонный шрифт</option>
            <option value="italic ">Курсив</option>
            <option value="lighter">Светлое начертание</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <span class="title">
Шрифт
</span><br>
<div class="form-group">
          <select class="select-txt">
            <option value="ordinary" selected>Обычный текст</option>
            <option value="bolder">Жирный шрифт</option>
            <option value="oblique">Наклонный шрифт</option>
            <option value="italic ">Курсив</option>
            <option value="lighter">Светлое начертание</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <span class="title">
Цвет
</span><br>
        <input type="text" id="hue" class="color" data-control="hue">
      </div>
</div>

  <script src="js/app.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```